# Adding a user to sharepoint group with only email Id

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom

I have a requirement to add external users to sharepoint groups. For this I created a Form in which the user inputs his outlook email address. Now on click of submit I want to add the user to a group using javascript only with his email address and name..Can this be done? How can I go about doing this?

Comment: The external user means that the user not been part of your organization yet?

Comment: Yes.. The user has an outlook account and we want to give the user permission to access the site.